# Rename multi index dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multiIndex pandas dataframe.

```
                            Issue
                       high  med   low
name   age    empId
Jack    44     Ab1      0     1     0
Bob     34     Ab2      0     0     1
Mike    52     Ab6      1     1     0
```

When I'm executing `df.columns` I'm getting the following result:-

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['Issue'], ['high', 'med', 'low']],
       labels=[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2]])
```

I'm looking to flatten this dataframe by renaming the Multi_index issue columns.

Expected output df:

```
name   age    empId  Issue_high  Issue_med  Issue_low
Jack    44     Ab1      0           1         0
Bob     34     Ab2      0           0         1
Mike    52     Ab6      1           1         0
```

I tried this:

```
df2 = df.rename(columns={'high':'Issue_high','low':'Issue_low','med':'Issue_med'}, level = 1)
```

Im getting error.
`rename() got an unexpected keyword argument "level"`

Is there any way to get the output structure?

## Edit: By using `df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)` I'm getting

```
                     Issue_high  Issue_med  Issue_low
name   age    empId  
Jack    44     Ab1      0           1         0
Bob     34     Ab2      0           0         1
Mike    52     Ab6      1           1         0

df.columns
>>> Index(['Issue_high',
   'Issue_med', 'Issue_low'],
  dtype='object')
```

Comment: You need to `reset_index` after your last edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) with `join` if all values are strings:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Or `format` or `f-string`s - working with numeric values in levels too:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
```

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
```

---

Last [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for convert `MultiIndex in Index` to columns:

```
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   name  age empId  Issue_high  Issue_med  Issue_low
0  Jack   44   Ab1           0          1          0
1   Bob   34   Ab2           0          0          1
2  Mike   52   Ab6           1          1          0
```

Comment: Can i flatten it again to bring name, age, empId as columns.

Comment: @Shubham - Just edited answer.